# How to disable, or hide system settings programmatically?

Tags: android, android-studio, settings

I do not want the user to open device settings, so I need to disable device settings.

I found way to open settings

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);
```

But I am looking for a way to disable it, how can I do that?

Comment: @GowthamanM I tried these solutions before I wrote my question. It is not useful.

Answer (score 3):

You can not disable system packages unless you make a custom rom. Besides that it is a huge security risk to allow developers to disable settings so the user can not stop the app.

Answer (score 0):

You may create custom launcher with kiosk mode to achieve your target. Note that this approach requires some actions from your users.

Related links 
https://developer.android.com/work/cosu.html
http://pvolan.blogspot.ru/2017/01/android-50-kiosk-mode-aka-super.html

Comment: Yes, It is for launcher but these links  are not useful.